# Is "you've been snuggledorfed" a hapax legomenon?

Tags: word-usage, frequency-analysis

Near the start of [Are Species "Real"?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tduwq0I4lYw) by Gutsick Gibbon, they say:

> I hate to say it, but you have been tricked. You've been duped. You have been bamboozled. And to put it rather bluntly, you've been snuggledorfed.

I tried googling and searching dictionaries for "snuggledorfed" and found nothing. From the context of the prior sentences I'd say it is meant to be connoted as a cute and comedic synonym to the terms "tricked", "duped", and "bamboozled".

Is this a unique usage of "snuggledorfed", or has it been used elsewhere?

Comment: (It occurs at about 1:15 in the video.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word is not **snuggledorfed**; it is **smeckledorfed** and has its origins in the august authority of "[The Spongegebob Fandom Forum](https://spongebob.fandom.com/f/p/4400000000000001431#:%7E:text=2020%20in%20Games-,Smeckledorf,high%20authority.)" in the section "Encyclopedia SpongeBobia"

It was suggested by the poster AnSon828511 on 01/06/2020in in "Games."

> Smeckledorf verb INFORMAL
>
> past tense: Smeckledorfed
>
> Fooled or deceived, especially in a work environment by someone of high authority.
>
> "He's taking all the credit. Can't you see we're being smeckledorfed?"
>
> Similar: trick deceive dupe bamboozle

I don't think that the word is sufficiently **straughtous*** to bring itself into the category of "hapax legomenon."

*In case you're wondering, I have just coined that word, said it, my wife has said it and it appears here in print and here only.

Comment: ... What makes it a word rather than a candidate and/or non-word?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth A question for the philosophy forum if I ever saw one. Please post!  We can then await an answer that will obviously reference Wittgenstein. :)

Answer (score 1):

*Hapax legomenon* is strictly an expression used by lexicographers of ancient Greek (as the name implies).  *Hapax* (απαξ) meaning *once* and *legomenon* (λεγομενον) meaning *being said*,  That is why Greybeard has carefully ensured that nothing about what he wrote prevented his 'coinage' from being printed more than once.

However, strictly speaking, Ancient Greek lexicons are a special case, since none of the 'hapax legomena' in these can cease to qualify other than if a treasure trove of the complete lost works of ancient Greek literature to reveal whether any word in the lexicon so described was really only ever used once or not.  It has only a peripheral connection with whether any such word was in fact newly minted.

Of course, language can change, and there is nothing to stop the hapax legomenon to be extended to include coinages which do catch on.